# Bteq logon failed

Tags: teradata

This is on AIX Linux :

Enter your logon or BTEQ command:

```
.logon 10.10.10.10/c-user-her
password:password
*** Warning: RDBMS CRASHED or SESSIONS RESET. RECOVERY IN PROGRESS.
```

Any Info would be appreciated.

Comment: make sure your IP address is correct.  Other than that, you could enable a trace (set COPANOMLOG=path/filename).  I think that'll work with BTEQ.

Comment: Your DBA will shoot you if that's your real password ;-)

Comment: PS - I edited it so your password is no longer showing, but you should definitely go and update your password if that indeed was your real password before :-)

Comment: Comments online seem to suggest that this is generally due to a network connectivity issue (despite the misleading error message, which I think is saying that it basically lost connection because the RDBMS crashed or the network session was reset).  Can you ping that IP address from the server?  Can you login to this database using one of the GUI tools using the .NET or ODBC driver connections (eg. Teradata SQL Assistant, Teradata Studio Express, etc)?  It's a client-side message I believe, not a Teradata error message, which would have a 4-digit error code.

Comment: @LokMac its was a masked logon details . nothing is real .

Comment: @LokMac I can ping that IP from Linux box . I was able to login SQL assistant in windows environment througn ODBC with those details .

Comment: Do you have any other Teradata box you can connect to with BTEQ?

Comment: @LokMac only they gave me login details for sql assistant in windows . for 1 box .